# Structs in Lua?

Tags: struct, lua

I searched but not found anything can help me.

I have the following C struct:

```
struct Home {
   int num;
   int city_ID;
   int area_ID;
};
```

How do I write this in Lua?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tables is the closest thing to a struct that you get in Lua:

```
local s = {}
s.num = 2
s.city_id = 234
s.area_id = 2345
```

Now you can use struct syntax on it:

```
print(s.area_id)
```

Comment: This could be written more concisely as `local s = {num=2,city_id=234,area_id=2345}.`

Answer (score 8):

Lua provides tables, which can be used as dynamic structs, in which fields are added dynamically.

You could create a table for your example with this code:

```
s = {
  num = 2,
  city_id = 234,
  area_id = 2345,
}
```

To access its fields, use `s.area_id`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Read [Lua 5.3 reference manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/).

You'll either use [tables](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.9) or (for `struct`-s implemented by some C code!) *userdata*.